# Has Esperanto ever been successfully reformed?

Tags: history, reforms

Many people have tried to change Esperanto to their own liking. Have any reform proposals ever entered the general language? (Are there, for example, Ido elements in current usage? – *No this is not an attempt to tout reforms, just something I’ve been wondering about!* :-)  )

Answer (score 10):

A real reform in the sense of replacing language elements by new elements has taken place in 1888, when Zamenhof, after an idea by [Edgar von Wahl](https://eo.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edgar_von_Wahl), in his ["Aldono al la Dua Libro"](http://anno.onb.ac.at/cgi-content/anno-buch?apm=0&aid=100081&teil=0103&seite=00000005&zoom=2) changed the temporal correlatives from *-an* to *-am* in order to avoid a collision with the accusative singular of the correlatives ending in *-a* (*kian* - *kia'n*).

From time to time the Esperanto Academy as authorised central institution has sanctioned alternatives to official elements (ekz. the permission to say *ark* instead of *arĥ*), but this no real reform, as the older forms remain valid (the Academy is not entitled to remove any official element).

There has been a considerable transfer from Ido to Esperanto, with some elements successfully entering the language (*-end-*, *farbo*), other ones still seeking wider recognition (*-oz-*, *-iz-*, *-iv-*). But this also cannot be called a reform, as we're dealing here with an augmentation of the lexicon, not the replacement of any forms.

For some people the preposition *far* has replaced *de* with the passive, but this is against the norm (see §6 of the Fundamenta Gramatiko) and not used by the majority of speakers.

Please feel free to correct my English.

Comment: Wiktionary says that _-aĉ-_ is borrowed from Italian _-accio_ and that Ido borrowed _-ach-_ from Esperanto _-aĉ-_. Which language got the word first?

Comment: I better drop this example, as I'm not sure anymore. They may have come at the same time: According to Berlina Komentario II, 26, _-aĉ-_ was proposed by Z at the end of 1906. In the brochure of IDO (p. 64) at the same time _-ac-_ is proposed, which was later changed to _-ach-_ because of more expressiveness (Gramatiko detaloza, 112), but not necessarily because of the form in Esperanto.

Answer (score 2):

If you're asking whether new elements have ever come into Esperanto, then clearly the answer is yes. As just one random example that came up in a recent discussion, the word *pigra* used to be found only in lists of alternatives to "mal-words." (In this case, as an alternative to *maldiligenta*.) Now it's an ordinary Esperanto word.